# How to adjust TextField width?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm re-writing a simple app which calculates averages. However, I have a hard time with a TextField. I would like it to be exactly as on a first screenshot.

The TextField's width is stretched, I don't want that. I want it to be exactly as it is on the screenshot.

Desired look:
[image: Desired look]

What I have: 
[image: What I have]

Code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';

class ArithmeticAverageScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('arithmetic_average_title').tr(),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Card(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.help),
                      title: Text('arithmetic_average_help').tr(),
                      subtitle: Text('arithmetic_average_help_content').tr(),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ) 
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            Card(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('arithmetic_average_your_grades', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5).tr(),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    Text('arithmetic_average_grades_one_at_a_time', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,).tr(),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    Text('arithmetic_average_grade', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2).tr(),
                    TextField()
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will help you make generic width on all devices, so here `width * 0.3` means it will take 30% of the screen width

```
 Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
          child: TextField(),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Row Widget, and put Expanded Widget as child Widget and inside that put your widgets, as Expanded will take up equal space.

```
return Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
       child: TextField();
    ),
    Expanded(
       child: Button();
    )
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When ever you want to play with height and width you can use the widget Container.If you want to play with a property which cannot found in the widget you are using wrap it with a widget with that property will help you.

```
Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 150),
  child: new TextField(
  decoration: new InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Grade',
   )
  )
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap your TextField and Button with two Flexible widgets and apply desired proportions, e.g. 1:2 which would give you following result:

```
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: TextField(),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                          child: Text('Hello'), onPressed: () {}),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
```

You can also replace the first Flexible with SizedBox and set an exact value, e.g:

```
                Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 100.0,
                      child: TextField(),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                          child: Text('Hello'), onPressed: () {}),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
```

[image]

TextField doesn't have an intrinsic size (width) constraint so it will always try to occupy all horizontal space. Flexible allows to constraint it to desired width in a Row.

Full example [on DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/0de480b0287860806378c3eebb295b37).